# How do i get a clone of my hashmap that is in an arraylist

Tags: java, collections

I need to change the key and value for a chosen index in my array-list that contains hash map. I know that to replace a key you need to first remove the key that is going to be replace and put a new one. But that doesn't save the position of the removed key and value. Thus i thought of iterating through my array-list of hash map and create them one by one in a new hash map in which I can add an if command for my chosen index let say 1,1 there it will change the index position that i wanted to be change and copy the ones that are not to be edited. I don't know how and the right way of how to copy. Please take note that I am just a beginner in java and trying to learn. What is the way to properly do this?

I tried just manually doing an update of key and value but it changed the position/index of where it was supposed to be.

```
import java.util.*;

public class sof {
    static ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> table = new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>>(); //2d ArrayList
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        setMatrix();
        print();
        System.out.println();
        editValue2();

    }

    static void print(){
        for(int x = 0; x < table.size();x++){
            System.out.println(table.get(x));
        }
    }

    static String setChar(){
        String result = "";
        Random random = new Random();
        for(int x = 1; x < 4 ; x++){
        result += (char)(32 + random.nextInt(95));
        }
        return result;
    }

    static void setRow(int x){
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> arr = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        for(int z=1; z <= x; z++){
            String ran = setChar();
            String rann = setChar();
            arr.put(ran,rann);
        }
        table.add(arr);         
    }

    static void Setmatrix(){
        Scanner row = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Row: ");
        int zz = row.nextInt();
        Scanner column = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Column: ");
        int z = column.nextInt();
        for(int x = 0; x <= zz-1; x++){
            setRow(z);
        }
    }

    static void editValue2(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String edited = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Row: ");
        int ind1 = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Col: ");
        int ind2 = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Key: ");
        String key = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Key: ");
        String value = sc.nextLine();
        int col=0;
        int row=0;
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> copy = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        for (LinkedHashMap<String, String> map : table){
            for(Map.Entry<String,String> set1 : map.entrySet()){
                int i = 0;
                if(ind1==0 && ind2==0){
                        copy.put(key,value);
                        copy.putAll(map);       
                }else{
                    if(ind1 == row&& ind2==col){
                        copy.put(key,value);
                    }
                    copy.put(set1.getKey(),set1.getValue());
                }

                col++;
            }
        row++;
        col=0;
            }
        map.clear();
        map.putAll(copy);
        copy.clear();
        copy=null;  
    }
}
```

I expect that I can edit both the key and value of any index in any given table. The keys also have to be unique.

Comment: To replace a value in an `ArrayList` at a given index, just use the `get` and `set` methods. There is no need to iterate over the entire list. Not to speak of iterating over all maps at all positions, when you want to modify exactly one. Regarding the `LinkedHashMap`, you are heading into the right direction, but your special case for index zero is unnecessary and doesn’t work. Further, there is no need for a cleanup like `copy.clear(); copy=null;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get and set the ArrayList value for the given index and to replace the key-value preserving the map index in the LinkedHashMap, you have to clone it with the new value. In that case, you are on the right track.

Edited code of your editValue2 method

```
int col = 0;

LinkedHashMap<String, String> copy = new LinkedHashMap<>();
// you can get the map from arrayList index
LinkedHashMap<String, String> map = table.get( ind1 ); // assuming ind1 is the arrayList index
for ( Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet() )
{
    // assuming ind2 is the map index
    if ( ind2 == col )
    {
        copy.put( key, value );
    }
    else
    {
        copy.put( entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() );
    }
    col++;
}
table.set( ind1, copy );
```